# How can I pickle a Python class method?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, multiprocessing, joblib

On Python 3.6, I have defined a class `foo` which instantiates an object `p`. On instantiation, the class performs a computationally expensive interpolation and 'attaches' an interpolating function to the object.

Once I have this done, I can call other class methods without the need to interpolate again. So far, so good.

A minimal working example is shown in the code below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.func = self.interp()


    def interp(self):
        def integrand(x): return self.shape(x)

        xpoints = np.arange(100)
        ypoints = [quad(
                        integrand, a=-np.inf, b=np.inf
                        )[0]/x for x in xpoints]

        I = interp1d(xpoints, ypoints)
        return I


    def shape(self, x):
        F = x**2  # complicated maths here
        return F
```

I then use the `p` object to perform a heavy task. I parallelize it for optimization. I use the `multiprocessing` library like so:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    results = pool.map(func, list(bar))  # func uses my p instance
```

for which I get an error `MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result...`, the traceback of which points to my interpolating function being unpickleable.

I have no idea how to pickle `interp1d` and I wouldn't like to change the structure of my current code as this has been very well thought through and I think it's in its most efficient format. Could I add another (few) lines to make my interpolating function top-level?

I have tried using `joblib`, which kept complaining about memory issues (even with 1 cpu used).

In my case, `multiprocessing` could really do the job. It actually finishes the job, outputs the result in the terminal, but fails to collect all the results together. All items in the iterable I am parallelizing for are completely independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pools use multiprocessing queues to transfer data between processes. These queues only work on pickleable data. Pickled functions are just stored by name and re-imported by the unpickler. Naturally, this means that they must be importable.

There are usually ways to work around these pickling problems, but save yourself the headaches and install `pathos` instead. Its multiprocessing pools use `dill` which can pickle almost anything.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that worked perfectly! I had been trying to use ``dill`` alone before, but to no avail. ``pathos`` is exactly what I needed. I am accepting your solution.